# AMP iframe Invalid height value: 500

Tags: iframe, amp-html

Frustrating as it is, with no proper documentation (or I'm missing it and can't find it), I don't know why my iframe is throwing error at the iframe:

```
<amp-iframe layout="responsive" src="https://giphy.com/embed/EiO0d5vsZSaZO" allowfullscreen="" width="847" height="507" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-layout"><i-amphtml-sizer style="display: block; padding-top: 59.8583%;"></i-amphtml-sizer><i-amphtml-scroll-container class="amp-active"><iframe class="i-amphtml-fill-content" name="amp_iframe0" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="https://giphy.com/embed/EiO0d5vsZSaZO#amp=1"></iframe></i-amphtml-scroll-container></amp-iframe>
```

The error in the console is:

```
Invalid height value:  507
```

Anyone has any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried asking [AMP issues](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) if this is an on going bug for `amp-iframe`?

Comment: No! Will post there. Thanks.